# Saving coordinates X,Y - find holes MySql

Tags: mysql, coordinates

Im currently creating a schema were user's are able to pick certain "boxes" which im saving in the database as X,Y points. (currently stored as simple Integers).

i.e. row 1 column 2 would be x:1 y:2

How do I find the first "empty/available" spot in the Database?

I.e. if all columns in Rows 1-3 would be taken, the answer should be X: 4, Y:1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to write a `proc` for this purpose. It searches first whether point(0, 0) is available, if not it increments to (0, 1) ...etc

Answer (score 0):

Something like this function (takes mx_rows, mx_cols as args):

```
set @i := 0;
set @j := 0;
set @tmp := 0;

while @i < @mx_rows DO
    set @j := 0;
    while @j < @mx_cols DO
        @tmp := select count(*) from POINTS
            where x = @j and y = @i;
        if @tmp == 0 then
            return (@j, @i);
        end if;
        set @j = @j + 1;
    end while;
    set @i = @i + 1;
end while;
```